# Performance algorithm - Ordering - Tree (data structure) only solution?

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem at hand, at first sight it looks easy and it is, however I am looking for some other solution (maybe more easy one):

Expressions:

```
V0
V1
V2
V3
V4
SumA = V1 + V2
SumB = SumA + V3
SumC = SumB + SumA
SumD = SumC + V0
```

As we can see here, the "base" variables are `V0, V1, V2, V3 and V4` (the value of each one of them is returned from DB queries)

**The user ask the software to return the result of `V1` and `SumC`.**

Solution that I know:

Find all necessary variables: V1, SumC, SumB, SumA, V3, V2

For performance I just want to process the math of each variable JUST ONE TIME.

This means that I need to order the expressions from "base expressions" to "top variables".

At this point I am only seeing a solution of the type "Tree (data structure)" > Get V1, V2 and V3
Then get SumA, after get SumB and only at last get SumC.

**Is there any other way to solve this problem?**

The final objective in this algorithm is to use with more complex variables and several "middle variables". So, performance is critical, I can't make the same math operation more than 1 time.

Comment: Have you checked the compiler output? Some compilers do this optimization for you.

Comment: Are `V0` through `V4` ordinary numbers? Are you sure these (rather trivial lookings) calculations are the bottleneck in your program?

Comment: Yes, the results of V0 through V4 are just ordinary numbers. I just want to be sure that I will not make the same math operation more than one time and this is only possible to achieve if I know the order in which I need to make them. I can only know SumC after knowing SumA and SumB, and "so on..."....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand - but I think you are referring to [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination),  [or something similar to it] which is a very common [compiler optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization).

One common way of doing this optimization is using a graph [which is actually a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)] of the expressions in the program, and adding iteratively new expressions.  The "sources" in your DAG are all initial variables [V0,V1,V2,V3,V4 in your example]. You can "know" which expression is redundant if you already calculated it - and avoid recalculating it.

[These lecture notes](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http://cs.gmu.edu/~white/CS640/Slides/CS640-2-03.ppt&ei=_jRjT5-4LcnVsgaKtrXEBQ&usg=AFQjCNF5QW1NHd_BYexUy5u-V1j-qGEd_Q&sig2=TlSW38bxmcBchkym3PgINw) seems to be a decent more detailed explanation [though I admit I did not read it all]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to build a tree with all expressions. Trees are the most simple data structure for this case.

Now let's assume you have these formulas:

```
SumA = v1 + v2
SumB = v1 + v2 + v3
SumC = ...
```

and the user asks for `SumB` (so you know *how* to calculate `SumC` but to make the user happy, you *don't have to*).

In Memory, this looks like so:

```
SumA = Add( v1, v2 )
SumB = Add( Add( v1, v2 ), v3 ) )
```

The next step is to define compare operators which tell whether two sub-trees are the same. Running those, you will notice that `Add( v1, v2 )` appears twice, so you can optimize:

```
SumA = Add( v1, v2 )
SumB = Add( SumA, v3 )
```

This means you can achieve the result by the minimum of calculations. The next step is to add caching to your operators: When someone asks their value, they should cache it so the next `getValue()` call can return the last result.

That means evaluating either `SumA` or `SumB` will fill the cache for `SumA`. Since you never ask for the value of `SumC`, it's never calculated and therefore costs nothing.

Comment: Aaron thank you for the contribution. Yes, like you I just see a solution: using a Tree/Graph structure. Amit's lecture notes proves that.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to speed this up is to use serialisation on level you can't get programatically unless you use your own hardware. Example:
[image]

Please ignore note on top right, this is stolen from my script :)

Case A:
100 * 4 cycles

Case B: 
First result takes 3 cycles, each next takes only 1 (serialisation, Ford factory like). - 102 cycles

102 vs 400 - roughly 4* the speed.

Modern CPUs can do this to some extent automatically, but it's pretty hard to measure it.
I've heard that ICC (intel C compiler) does optimize it's assembly to exploit this as much as possible, maybe that's partially why they beat everything else on intel CPU's :)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but as you can see, your "expression" is ordered, you made it in some "mental process". I just want to know if I can only order it using a "tree solution" or if there is some other way without using tree (data structure)

Comment: I doubt there is anything better than this, you always need partial calculation. Slight modification:

SumC += (SumB = (Sumc = SumA = V1 + V2) + V3);

Comment: The `register` qualifier is not C11 only; it's pre-ANSI C and seldom has any effect in modern compilers.

Comment: Well compilers don't have to respect it, I know. Especially on x86 when you one have 4 'usable' GPR.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify it into this and eliminate the middle step:

```
SumA = (V1 + V2)*2
SumC = V3 + SumA
```

Comment: He wrote that he needs all variables, not just SumC.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I saw that only v1 and SumC had to be returned which is why I suggested this.